# mvc4 Recaptcha with Json ActionView

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have recently moved over to MVC4 and i am having difficulty changing the Recaptcha in the Controller so that it can use Json for instance this works

```
 //This Works
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult create(Registration registration)
    {
        if (!ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "key-value"))
        { return Content("Wrong Captcha please try again"); }


    }
 // This does not work it gives an error saying
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult create(Registration registration)
    {

        if (!ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "key-value"))
        { return Content("Wrong Captcha please try again"); }


    }
```

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'**
That is the error that I get when i switch to Json is there any way to correct that?

Comment: The first one works because ContentResult inherits from ActionResult. Why are you trying to return 'Content("Wrong Captcha please try again")' instead of 'Json("Wrong Captcha please try again")'?

Comment: ohh wow I am surprised it was that easy I been trying to do every other method to try to get it to work i am new to this whole mvc json thing thanks alot